# Ionic Exit APP not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set `ng-click="ionic.Platform.exitApp()"` to a button but it dosen't work, i also tried `ng-click="exitApp()"` and `ng-click="$ionic.Platform.exitApp()"`but it dosen't work either.

I'm using Ionic Creator, according to this docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/ it should be quite simple, but i don't know how to correctly set this adjust. I also tryied to add a module into Ionic Creator as:

```
angular.module('app.exit', []).exit(function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

  var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();

  var isWebView = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
  var isIPad = ionic.Platform.isIPad();
  var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
  var isWindowsPhone = ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone();

  var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();

  ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app
});
```

Adding this module console log prints: "exit is not a function"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use this [ExitApp Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-exitapp)

To use, add the plugin by `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-exitapp` and then add the following code to your `app.js`

```
angular.module('XYZApp', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $rootScope) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  // For exit on back button press
   $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
     if ($rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // or // ionic.Platform.exitApp(); both work
     } else if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
         $ionicHistory.goBack();
     } else {
        $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
        // "Press back button again to exit" : show toast                
        setTimeout(function() {
            $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false;
        }, 2000); // reset if user doesn't press back within 2 seconds, to fire exit
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, 101);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chiragh Dewan,

But it dosen't work either, i added this:

```
angular.module('XYZApp', []).run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $rootScope) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  // For exit on back button press
   $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
     if ($rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // or // ionic.Platform.exitApp(); both work
     } else if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
         $ionicHistory.goBack();
     } else {
        $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
        // "Press back button again to exit" : show toast                
        setTimeout(function() {
            $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false;
        }, 2000); // reset if user doesn't press back within 2 seconds, to fire exit
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, 101);
 });
}
);
```

... into a new JS file called exit.js 
Then i added the module XYZApp into the Ionic Creator code settings Angular modules
The last step i added the cordova-plugin-exitapp

I tryied ng-click="navigator.app.exitApp()" and ng-click="ionic.Platform.exitApp()" and none of them seems to work.

U can see the project here: https://creator.ionic.io/share/html/2d9b0126751e#/menu/contacto

Thanks